# Java Generic wild card bounds not working

Tags: java, generics

I have encountered a situation where I fail to understand the reasoning behind the exhibited compiler behavior. I have written following code snippet-

```
public class OutgoingStub<T> {
    public OutgoingStub<T> tryThis(T val){
        return new OutgoingStub<T>();
    }

    public void f(Set<? extends Number> set){

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<? extends Number> set = new HashSet<Integer>();

        **OutgoingStub<Set<? extends Number>> stub = Mocktest.mock(set);** //Unable to assign the reuturn value in a variable. compiler complains.
    }
}

class Mocktest {
    public static <T> OutgoingStub<T> mock(T val){
        return new OutgoingStub<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should explicitly tell the compiler what type parameter to use when calling `mock`:

```
OutgoingStub<Set<? extends Number>> stub = Mocktest.<Set<? extends Number>>mock(set);
```

Otherwise there is an ambiguity as to what the type parameter of `mock` should be. This is called a *type witness*, and it's necessary when the compiler can't [infer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) the type.

This is explained in detail in [JLS §15.12.2.8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.8) (this is the Java 7 JLS -- see the note below).

**Note** that you no longer need a type witness in Java 8 (i.e. your current code would compile fine in Java 8).